# Core animation (size change) with autolayout challenge

Tags: ios, swift, animation, autolayout

I have a piece of core animation by use of 2 methods in order to give appearance that the object is growing in size from the centre-outwards from the existing location...

(1) viewDidLayoutSubviews()

> self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(187, 249, 0, 0)

which is in the centre of the screen for this imageView object

(2) viewDidAppear()
 - with animation block of duration 1 second. e.g.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 1.5, options: [], animations: {

        self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(16, 70, 343, 358)

        }, completion: nil)
```

which puts object where I want it to show in full size, for the specific screen size.

When I use the **x and y coordinates for CGRectMake**(...) on the iPhone size I'm looking for they work fine, But when I try on simulator with different screen sizes, it doesn't work in conjunction with the Autolayout constraints, but overrides the existing Constraints.

**Question(s)...**

Is there a way of making this animation work by centering it proportional to the screen size somehow, rather than explicit coordinates and sizes? via CGRectMake...? (...which seems to show a clash between use of Autolayout and Animation)

Ideally I'm looking for an elegant simple solution? or am I at the limits of the tech?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set imageView location using autolayout constraints & give it a size constraint and by taking an outlet from it you can animate height to increase leaving all other constraints working

> @IBOutlet var myViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
>
> UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations:
>   { 
>       () -> Void in
>
> ```
>         self.myViewHeight.constant = 300
>
>         self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
>         }, completion:nil)
> ```

You should take the outlet from the constraint itself like control+drag on Label.top = topMargin

[image: You should take the outlet from the constraint itself]

Comment: When I create an IBOutlet from the storyboard to Code ViewController, the options for the object are to create with UIImageView, rahter than NSLayoutConstraint!. Is there something else I need to add to try out your idea above?

Comment: Additionally CGRectMake, still requires exact x, y, width, height for final layout for the animation, thus from what I can see there is still a clash between animation and auto layout

Comment: You will center your image view in super view X, Y.
then you will give it an aspect ration of 1:1
then height constraint = 0 which you will take it as an outlet
then you will animate height 
self.myViewHeight.constant = 300

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, as I'm new to Core Animation. Haven't played with constraints that way before so, this was new. I learnt something new. I added more constraints for 'Trailing' and 'Leading' for the image to create the appearance of the original simulation when using CGRectMake. I thought there may be a solution using CGRectMake, but this as a work around does the job. Thank you!